# Mathematical duality of controllability and observability

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

It is well known that controllability and observability are mathematical duals. So my question is, can algorithms that are proposed to check controllability be used to check observability as well?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. But more precisely, reachability and observability are duals. So any algorithm that is designed to check reachability of $(A, B)$ can be used to check the observability of $(A,C)$ by just checking the reachability of $(A^T,C^T)$ and vice versa.

Comment: It seems in nonlinear dynamical systems, controllability and observablity are not duals anymore, right?

Comment: After a quick search I believe it is the case for certain systems, see for example: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266366723_Duality_of_observability_and_controllability_properties_of_nonlinear_dynamic_systems. If you happen to construct a function that converts two problems to each other, then you could use the same algorithm for both problems.

Comment: Thank you @obareey. Here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030305/what-is-the-difference-between-controllability-and-reachability you have said that reachability and controllability is not equivalent in the case of discrete time linear systems. So how I can use duality between reachability and observability to infer duality between controllability and observability?

Comment: In general, you cannot. You have to check the specific conditions that the duality exists. For example, if $A$ does not have any zero eigenvalues, then duality exists between controllability and observability (in discrete time systems). Controllability is actually the dual of constructability in every case for linear systems..